# Blocking websites on Tomato firmware connected to VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, tomato

At work, we have some Asus RT-N16 routers setup with Tomato Firmware, so the off-site programs can be part of our internal network. It's setup with OpenVPN, and works great for allowing the users to use our proxy server, our file server, etc.

I have had a few of the sites request for Facebook to be blocked. I figured it would be easy, given the number of tutorials available online (Go to Access Restrictions, create a new rule, enter `facebook` to block all requests for Facebook). Seems simple enough...

I added the rule, and let the router reset just in case. The other site can still access Facebook!

I feel it's due to the VPN connection, but I do not know where to go from here. I would think if it was blocked at the router, and the router is doing the VPN (not the client PCs!), that it would still have its own set of rules. Am I missing something here?

I have SSH and Web Console access to the routers from my main site. The settings I put in are below:

[image]

Comment: Instead of simply `facebook`, use `*.facebook.*`, and check the HTTPD-requested files too.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Even though every tutorial says to just use `facebook` to match it anywhere in the server name?